# GroupBy Date in Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, group-by

**Hi,**
Is there anyway to apply Groupby property in core data.

**What I am Looking for**

I have multiple records say 45 of different date and times that contains count of Number of steps a Patient walk.

**Say** 15 records from May 27 on different times.
        15 records from May 26 on different times.
        15 records from May 25 on different times.

I want to GroupBy them by Date but not time.
i.e. I want Sum of all records steps from each day.

**What I have done so far**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchingRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *logsDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:MISFIT_ACTIVITY_LOG inManagedObjectContext:[PAPersistanceManager sharedInstance].mainManagedObjectContext];
[fetchingRequest setEntity:logsDescription];

NSAttributeDescription* timeStamp = [logsDescription.attributesByName objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
NSAttributeDescription* logId = [logsDescription.attributesByName objectForKey:@"activityLogId"];
NSAttributeDescription* steps = [logsDescription.attributesByName objectForKey:@"steps"];
NSAttributeDescription* syncStatus = [logsDescription.attributesByName objectForKey:@"syncStatus"];

[fetchingRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:timeStamp,logId,steps,syncStatus,nil]];

NSError *fetchError;
[fetchingRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"steps" nil]];
[fetchingRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
//[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSArray *fetchResult = [[PAPersistanceManager sharedInstance].mainManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchingRequest error:&fetchError];
```

**Result**

```
 <_PFArray 0x169821f0>(
 {
   steps = 4;
 },
 {
  steps = 60;
 },
 {
  steps = 110;
 },
 {
  steps = 348;
 },
 {
  steps = 66;
 },
 {
  steps = 104;
 } 
 )
```

All the entries are from May 27 But it returns me 6 different objects instead of giving me the Sum of all steps.

Is there anyway to do it other than Looping through all entries and using comparison ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think that you need to use NSExpression and NSExpressionDescription, I am quite unclear about your use case though ?

Answer (score 0):

You can normalise your data by storing a new NSString key in your managed objects that contains a string representation of your date that can be logically ordered.

So say, if you have 3 dates May 26 2015, May 27 2015 and (for the sake of it) June 28 2014. Your dates represented as strings would be (in ascending order):

- 2014-06-28
- 2015-05-26
- 2015-05-27

You can then use this key as the section key using `NSFetchedResultsController`. This will give you the equivalent functionality (sort of) of an MySQL GROUP BY.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Danny Bravo for your answer, You mean to make changes in DataModel ?